# How does one improve the Help Center documentation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Parts of the Help Center documentation, such as images, are out of date as Stack Overflow has continued to evolve. For example, from [the 10k Moderation page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) the image used for the review and tools queue:

[image: Image showing old review and tools links]

However, it's now changed to the following:

[image: New image of reviews and tools]

I don't see how to propose a fix, but would love help to figure out how to do so.

Comment: You can propose the fix here on meta.

Comment: One does not simply improve the help center documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see something which is out of date in the help center, or anywhere with regards to the site itself, or something which is incorrect, then post it here as you have done, either a feature-request to fix the incorrection (often used more for spelling or grammar issues - Knuth help you if you happen to suggest a pluralization fix), or as a bug report when pictures as shown are outdated.

In general, these issues will get fixed when pointed out, however, the timing of the fix greatly depends on how busy everyone is, how many views the page is getting, and how damaging the existing problem is.

Comment: On another note - the question posted raises an opportunity for SO to make the help center more wiki like so that people can update it.  Free help for Joel Spolsky.

Comment: @JonH - It would require some doing to make those pages wiki like, perhaps they could use tag wikis. If that did happen though, it seems like the community could keep them up to date-ish. The company does a fairly good job of creating the help content...making it findable on the other hand.

Comment: @JonH some pages can be edited by moderators directly, others are generic for *all sites* so they can't be edited.

Comment: Fun fact: help center articles are stored as posts in the system (at least the ones that can be edited by mods, not sure about the ones that are generic for all sites).